# .NET WCF Soap Service returns no response because of request size

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

I have a WCF Soap Service which I tried to call from SoapUI and my Java program. I am reading an Excel file from Java side and send it to .NET side.

Excel file has 37 columns and can include up to 100 rows. I read all the rows one by one and add them to a list. In one item of the list, there is a list of key-value objects of each cell in a single row.

Here is my problem. The service works well for limited number of rows. I looked at the maximum content-length I could send successfully which is 65536. If I send a request which has content length more than 65536, the service returns nothing.

If I send the request from Java project, I get this error:

> Could not send Message.; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '400: Bad Request' when communicating with ...

In the web.config file of .NET project, there are no limitations that I know about request size.

### Web.Config

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
  <httpRuntime/>
</system.web>
```

### My request from SoapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:pas="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/..." xmlns:pas1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/..." xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/...">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:ListSegments>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pas:UserName>tst</pas:UserName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pas1:DetailList>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <arr:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
                     <arr:Key>No</arr:Key>
                     <arr:Value>1</arr:Value>
                  </arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
                  ....
               </arr:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
               <arr:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
                     <arr:Key>No</arr:Key>
                     <arr:Value>2</arr:Value>
                  </arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
                  ....
               </arr:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
               ....
            </pas1:DetailList>
          <tem:request>
       <tem:ListSegments>
    <soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are default values for the limitations. One of them is maxAllowedContentLength, which should have a default value of 30000000, which is roughly 28.6MB. So it's probably not this you are experiencing.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

It might be the `maxReceivedMessageSize` which are usually set in the bindings part of the web.config, which you do not seem to have. Maybe they are set in the code?

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
       maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Maybe there is a config file at a higher "level" that have set a default value. This could be the machine.config file or another Web.config depending on the setup (if this is running in IIS).

Comment: Thank you so much. After adding basicHttpBinding part, my problem solved. Also thank you for giving information about all those possibilities.